# Laravel one page auth (this same field name)

Tags: php, laravel

How can I add custom error bags to deafault auth in laravel? Because I have two forms (login and registration) on one page and If user make mistake he should see error below correct input but both forms have this same names.

I don't want integrate in vendor files.

I know how to solve this problem, only need to edit:

```
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers.php
```

and add error bags:

```
protected function sendFailedLoginResponse(Request $request)
{
    return redirect()->back()
        ->withInput($request->only($this->username(), 'remember'))
        ->withErrors([
            $this->username() => Lang::get('auth.failed'),
        ], 'login' <--);
}
```

**But how can I do it without edit vendor files?**

Comment: please show the view of that page.

Comment: @GrowingDev https://gist.github.com/anonymous/bb35f57609bcc5841d38452b67614639

Comment: change the name for one of them. this should help you to tell the difference from the other one. I'm assuming the errors is in the password and email fields. change those fields in the registration form to `registration_email` and `registration_password`, this should do the trick.

Comment: I don't want rename input name :)

Answer (score 0):

That's because the errors you are returning for both forms have the same name. `@if ($errors->has('email'))` for login and signup. Any of the two that returns `@if ($errors->has('email'))` will definitely show on the other. Because the errors are stored in a session and the `has()` method just check if the session exist and displays the error.

Comment: Yes, I know why is conflict but I'm looking for good solution. I don't want rename input name or edit vendor files.

Comment: Show some sample code of your controller where the form is submitting.